# Accidentally renamed file in Ubuntu /usr/bin

Tags: linux, ubuntu-22.04

I have accidentally renamed the file in /usr/bin and have no idea about its previous name.
Current name is "[". How can I find out its previous name?

```
$ objdump -x '/usr/bin/[' 

/usr/bin/[:     file format elf64-x86-64
/usr/bin/[
architecture: i386:x86-64, flags 0x00000150:
HAS_SYMS, DYNAMIC, D_PAGED
start address 0x0000000000002c20

Program Header:
    PHDR off    0x0000000000000040 vaddr 0x0000000000000040 paddr 0x0000000000000040 align 2**3
         filesz 0x00000000000002d8 memsz 0x00000000000002d8 flags r--
  INTERP off    0x0000000000000318 vaddr 0x0000000000000318 paddr 0x0000000000000318 align 2**0
         filesz 0x000000000000001c memsz 0x000000000000001c flags r--
    LOAD off    0x0000000000000000 vaddr 0x0000000000000000 paddr 0x0000000000000000 align 2**12
         filesz 0x00000000000012e8 memsz 0x00000000000012e8 flags r--
    LOAD off    0x0000000000002000 vaddr 0x0000000000002000 paddr 0x0000000000002000 align 2**12
         filesz 0x00000000000069c6 memsz 0x00000000000069c6 flags r-x
    LOAD off    0x0000000000009000 vaddr 0x0000000000009000 paddr 0x0000000000009000 align 2**12
         filesz 0x00000000000021d8 memsz 0x00000000000021d8 flags r--
    LOAD off    0x000000000000bc50 vaddr 0x000000000000cc50 paddr 0x000000000000cc50 align 2**12
         filesz 0x0000000000000448 memsz 0x0000000000000588 flags rw-
 DYNAMIC off    0x000000000000bc70 vaddr 0x000000000000cc70 paddr 0x000000000000cc70 align 2**3
         filesz 0x00000000000001b0 memsz 0x00000000000001b0 flags rw-
    NOTE off    0x0000000000000338 vaddr 0x0000000000000338 paddr 0x0000000000000338 align 2**3
         filesz 0x0000000000000030 memsz 0x0000000000000030 flags r--
    NOTE off    0x0000000000000368 vaddr 0x0000000000000368 paddr 0x0000000000000368 align 2**2
         filesz 0x0000000000000044 memsz 0x0000000000000044 flags r--
0x6474e553 off    0x0000000000000338 vaddr 0x0000000000000338 paddr 0x0000000000000338 align 2**3
         filesz 0x0000000000000030 memsz 0x0000000000000030 flags r--
EH_FRAME off    0x000000000000aa70 vaddr 0x000000000000aa70 paddr 0x000000000000aa70 align 2**2
         filesz 0x000000000000010c memsz 0x000000000000010c flags r--
   STACK off    0x0000000000000000 vaddr 0x0000000000000000 paddr 0x0000000000000000 align 2**4
         filesz 0x0000000000000000 memsz 0x0000000000000000 flags rw-
   RELRO off    0x000000000000bc50 vaddr 0x000000000000cc50 paddr 0x000000000000cc50 align 2**0
         filesz 0x00000000000003b0 memsz 0x00000000000003b0 flags r--

Dynamic Section:
  NEEDED               libc.so.6
  INIT                 0x0000000000002000
  FINI                 0x00000000000089b4
  GNU_HASH             0x00000000000003b0
  STRTAB               0x0000000000000978
  SYMTAB               0x00000000000003d8
  STRSZ                0x00000000000002d5
  SYMENT               0x0000000000000018
  DEBUG                0x0000000000000000
  PLTGOT               0x000000000000ce20
  PLTRELSZ             0x0000000000000480
  PLTREL               0x0000000000000007
  JMPREL               0x0000000000000e68
  RELA                 0x0000000000000d48
  RELASZ               0x0000000000000120
  RELAENT              0x0000000000000018
  FLAGS                0x0000000000000008
  FLAGS_1              0x0000000008000001
  VERNEED              0x0000000000000cc8
  VERNEEDNUM           0x0000000000000001
  VERSYM               0x0000000000000c4e
  RELACOUNT            0x0000000000000003

Version References:
  required from libc.so.6:
    0x0d696913 0x00 08 GLIBC_2.3
    0x06969194 0x00 07 GLIBC_2.14
    0x069691b3 0x00 06 GLIBC_2.33
    0x0d696914 0x00 05 GLIBC_2.4
    0x069691b4 0x00 04 GLIBC_2.34
    0x09691974 0x00 03 GLIBC_2.3.4
    0x09691a75 0x00 02 GLIBC_2.2.5

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .interp       0000001c  0000000000000318  0000000000000318  00000318  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  1 .note.gnu.property 00000030  0000000000000338  0000000000000338  00000338  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  2 .note.gnu.build-id 00000024  0000000000000368  0000000000000368  00000368  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  3 .note.ABI-tag 00000020  000000000000038c  000000000000038c  0000038c  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  4 .gnu.hash     00000024  00000000000003b0  00000000000003b0  000003b0  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  5 .dynsym       000005a0  00000000000003d8  00000000000003d8  000003d8  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  6 .dynstr       000002d5  0000000000000978  0000000000000978  00000978  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  7 .gnu.version  00000078  0000000000000c4e  0000000000000c4e  00000c4e  2**1
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  8 .gnu.version_r 00000080  0000000000000cc8  0000000000000cc8  00000cc8  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  9 .rela.dyn     00000120  0000000000000d48  0000000000000d48  00000d48  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 10 .rela.plt     00000480  0000000000000e68  0000000000000e68  00000e68  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 11 .init         00000025  0000000000002000  0000000000002000  00002000  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 12 .plt          00000310  0000000000002030  0000000000002030  00002030  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 13 .plt.got      00000010  0000000000002340  0000000000002340  00002340  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 14 .plt.sec      00000300  0000000000002350  0000000000002350  00002350  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 15 .text         00006361  0000000000002650  0000000000002650  00002650  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 16 .fini         00000012  00000000000089b4  00000000000089b4  000089b4  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
 17 .rodata       00001a6f  0000000000009000  0000000000009000  00009000  2**5
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 18 .eh_frame_hdr 0000010c  000000000000aa70  000000000000aa70  0000aa70  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 19 .eh_frame     00000658  000000000000ab80  000000000000ab80  0000ab80  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 20 .ctors        00000010  000000000000cc50  000000000000cc50  0000bc50  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 21 .dtors        00000010  000000000000cc60  000000000000cc60  0000bc60  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 22 .dynamic      000001b0  000000000000cc70  000000000000cc70  0000bc70  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 23 .got          000001e0  000000000000ce20  000000000000ce20  0000be20  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 24 .data         00000098  000000000000d000  000000000000d000  0000c000  2**5
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
 25 .bss          00000138  000000000000d0a0  000000000000d0a0  0000c098  2**5
                  ALLOC
 26 .gnu_debugaltlink 00000049  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000c098  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
 27 .gnu_debuglink 00000034  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000c0e4  2**2
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
SYMBOL TABLE:
no symbols
```

Comment: A file called `[` is supposed to be in `/usr/bin`. Are you sure you've renamed something?

Comment: Insane suggestion: sha1sum the file and google the sha1-- well known sha1s are sometimes indexed

Comment: Tools in `bin` are not as potentially dangerous as tools in `sbin`. You may risk `/usr/bin/[ --help` or simply `/usr/bin/[` and see what happens. If you decide to do it then please [edit] and post the output. Maybe it's the genuine `[`, like the first comment suggests. OTOH if it's something else then renaming it back won't be enough because you've overwritten the real `[`.